# External javascript window.onload firing early

Tags: javascript, onload, external-js

I have a page that references an external javascript file, and when I tell it run a function onload, it is giving me errors (I assume because it is firing before the page is loaded.) "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

What do I need to do here to fire run() after the page is loaded?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
window.onload = run();

function run() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "found it";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I would accept both of your answers if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
window.onload = run;
```

When you do:

```
window.onload = run();
```

You're actually *running* the function called `run`, and then assigning its return-value (`undefined` in this case) to `window.onload`.

This function is running before the page even gets loaded (since you are running it explictly by doing `run()`), at which time the `div` with id `test` doesn't even exist. This is why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
window.onload = run
```

When you do `window.onload = run()` you are immediately executing `run()` and assign whatever is *returned* to the `window.onload` property. This is why it’s not working correctly.